# href to a modal and a function at the same time in bootstrap framework?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form like this in html:

```
<form class="well span9 offset1" action="/summary/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
        <label class="control-label" for ="inputIcon">Type or paste your text into box:</label>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <textarea rows="15" class="span9"></textarea> 

            </div>
            </div>


        <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="input_text" />
        Send me the copy of summary by e-mail.

        </fieldset><br />
        <a href="#summaryModal" data-toggle="modal"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary offset3">Summarize</button></a>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
</form>
```

While the user submits the form I want this form to process in summary function and return the result to the function in a modal in bootstrap. But instead of going to the function it just opens the popup(modal). I am returning to this same template from the function with the result. How can I do this? Do I need Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided your JavaScript functions, let me assume you have them in place. Yes, you must use AJAX for this to work. Here are the steps you must follow:

1. Your button's syntax must look like: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary offset3"
   onClick="summaryFunction()">Summarize</button>`
2. On clicking the button, fire a JavaScript function (in this case, let's call it summaryFunction()).
3. The function must post the details from the form to a PHP page that returns data in JSON format. ([This might help](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/))
4. Use $('#divId').innerHTML to populate the modal window's content using what's returned by the PHP page.
5. Fire the modal window using $('#divId').modal();

Hope it helps.

Here's an example:
Let the button fire a JavaScript function called summaryFunction() using the above syntax.
The JavaScript function looks like this:

```
<script>
function summaryFunction(){
$text = $('#textAreaId').val();
$.post("test.php", { "postedText": text },
function(data){
$('#modalInnerDiv').innerHTML = data.response;
$('#summaryModal').modal();
}, "json");
}
</script>
```

Make sure you provide an ID to your textarea element. Replace test.php with your PHP file. It must look for a posted value of name postedText. Put your reply into an array of key "response". Example `$reply = array("response" => $response)` and then serialize it into JSON using json_encode(). Your PHP file must echo this JSON value.

Have an empty div inside your modal with ID #modalInnerDiv. It's content will be filled with the reply from the PHP page and it'll be displayed in a modal window.

Comment: I haven't created any Javascript function yet. I am completely new to Ajax and somehow to Javascript to.